# I am not able to find Mono setup for RHEL 5.5 from Mono web site can any one guide me

Tags: linux, for-loop, mono, system, installation

I am new to linux and mono but i want to learn how run asp.net application in RHEL with apache

Comment: Search for Centos and mod_Mono. Centos is free implementation of RHEL, so you can apply the same tutorials. Mod_mono is the Apache module for running Mono. I supose you should install apache, php, imagemagic, mono and mod_mono.

Answer (score 0):

have u installed apache in RHEL?

If not, You can install apache by installing it from terminal console of RHEL and entering:

## yum install apache*

Create the file "/etc/yum.repos.d/mono.repo" and add the following lines :

```
[Mono]
name=Mono Stack (RHEL_5)
type=rpm-md
baseurl=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Mono/RHEL_5/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Mono/RHEL_5/repodata/repomd.xml.key
enabled=1
```

After that, open up your terminal and type:

## yum install mono-complete

Comment: ya i installed apache. if i install apache  will it install Mono automatically ?

Comment: i have edited the previous post, that should do the install for mono